# Optimal lock file method

Tags: c++, unix, file, locking

Windows has an option to open a file with exclusive access rights. Unix doesn't.

In order to ensure exclusive access to some file or device, it is common practice in Unix to use a lock file usually stored in the /var/lock directory.

The C instruction `open( "/var/lock/myLock.lock", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0666 )` returns -1 if the lock file already exist, otherwise it creates it. The function is atomic and ensures there is not race condition.

When the resource is released, the lock file is deleted by the following instruction
`remove( "/var/lock/myLock.lock" )`.

There are two problems with this method.

1. The program may terminate without removing the lock. For instance because it is killed,  crashes or whatever. The lock file remains in place, and will prevent any access to the resource even though it is not used anymore.
2. The lock file is created with group and world write privilege but it is a common practice to configure accounts to use a permission mask that will clear the group and world write permission. Thus, if we had a reliable method to determine that the lock is orphan (not use), a user not owner of the file will not be allowed to remove it.

For the record, I use the lock file to ensure exclusive access to the device connected to the serial port (/dev/ttyUSBx in fact). Advisory method, requiring cooperation, is OK. But exclusive access should be ensured between different users.

Is there a better synchronization method than the lock file?  How to determine if the process who created the lock file is still running? 
How to make it possible for another user to remove the lock file if not in use?

One solution I came up with was to use the file as Unix socket file. If the file exist, try to connect using the file. If it fails, we may assume the owner process of the file is dead. This requires to have a thread looping on socket `accept()` in the owner process. Unfortunately, the system wouldn't be atomic anymore.

Comment: No one seems to have mentioned the obvious answer, which may or may not work for you. POSIX requires stream ops to be atomic by default, and there's an internal file lock to handle this. So, if you can do everything you want in  a single `fprintf`, for example, then you're done.

Comment: @EML: if that's correct, that's good information. Do you have a source to reference?

Answer (score 45):

Take a look at the enlightening presentation [File Locking Tricks and Traps](http://perl.plover.com/yak/flock/):

> This short talk presents several common pitfalls of file locking and a few useful tricks for using file locking more effectively.

**Edit:** To address your questions more precisely:

> Is there a better synchronization method than the lock file?

As @Hasturkun already mentioned and as the presentation above told, the system call you need to use is [`flock(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock). If the resource you'd like to share across many users is already file-based (in your case it is `/dev/ttyUSBx`), then you can *`flock` the device file itself*.

> How to determine if the process who created the lock file is still running?

You don't have to determine this, as the `flock`-ed lock will be automatically released upon closing the file descriptor associated with your file, even if the process was terminated.

> How making it possible for another user to remove the lock file if not in use?

If you would lock the device file itself, then there will be no need to remove the file. Even if you would decide to lock an ordinary file in `/var/lock`, with `flock` you will not need to remove the file in order to release the lock.

Comment: I wish I could vote your answer up again for the extra details

Answer (score 22):

You should probably be using [`flock()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock), as in

```
fd = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666); // open or create lockfile
//check open success...
rc = flock(fd, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB); // grab exclusive lock, fail if can't obtain.
if (rc)
{
    // fail
}
```

Comment: Good point. Note that it should be 0666 (octal) and not 666 and the O_EXCL option should also be used. What about the file permission issue ? If another user created the file, the open call will fail even if the file already exist and is in use because a write access is requested. If a read access was requested, is it possible to lock on it ?

Comment: Oops, the O_EXCL should not be used to allow opening an existing file. Though the write access may cause it to fail if the file is readonly fo the the user. Flock is independent of file permission and would this work even if the file is read only. The umask() function allows to clear the permission mask when creating the file.

Comment: Mind that (on Linux) any program that doesn't call `flock` to check for an existing lock will be able to arbitrarily read/write the file, even if an exclusive lock by another process exists.

Comment: Unfortunately, this method does not work if you are running on read-only filesystem and if you do not have access any writable location.

Comment: @mvp: Well, it's difficult to create a lock file on a read-only filesystem. You can still `flock()` some agreed upon file in a read-only FS though, so long as you can `open()` it.

Comment: @Hasturkun: nope, `flock(fd, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB)` does NOT work on readonly filesystem. I tried `fcntl()` as well without any luck. I wish there was Windows-style global mutex to solve this, but alas, Linux does not support it either.

Comment: @mvp: That's not the case. I just tried it myself, opened the file with `O_RDONLY`, where the file was on a read-only mounted ext4 filesystem. It acquired the lock with no issues. (as an aside, for your global mutexes, go read on POSIX semaphores, via `sem_open`)

Comment: @mvp: I would like to note that `lockf()` requires a writable file, but `flock()` doesn't. `fcntl()` with `F_SETLK` requires a readable fd for read locks, and a writable fd for write locks. also, `flock()` won't work over NFS (but `fcntl()` should).

Answer (score 8):

The answer of Hasturkun is the one that has put me on track.

Here is the code I use

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

/*! Try to get lock. Return its file descriptor or -1 if failed.
 *
 *  @param lockName Name of file used as lock (i.e. '/var/lock/myLock').
 *  @return File descriptor of lock file, or -1 if failed.
 */
int tryGetLock( char const *lockName )
{
    mode_t m = umask( 0 );
    int fd = open( lockName, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666 );
    umask( m );
    if( fd >= 0 && flock( fd, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB ) < 0 )
    {
        close( fd );
        fd = -1;
    }
    return fd;
}

/*! Release the lock obtained with tryGetLock( lockName ).
 *
 *  @param fd File descriptor of lock returned by tryGetLock( lockName ).
 *  @param lockName Name of file used as lock (i.e. '/var/lock/myLock').
 */
void releaseLock( int fd, char const *lockName )
{
    if( fd < 0 )
        return;
    remove( lockName );
    close( fd );
}
```

Comment: it's probably worth swapping 'remove' and 'close' in the 'releaseLock' function.

Comment: This code is close to correct, but not quite, therefore making it buggy and not thread-safe. You should mention that or fix it. You shouldn't be removing the lock file at the end--just closing it. The lock file's presence is not what indicates the lock is taken, it is whether or not `flock()` was successful. A better approach would be to write the PID of the process which owns the flock-based lock into the file. The presence or absence of a PID written into the file indicates to outsiders and others now if the lock is taken. Of course, what `flock()` returns is the only perfect indicator.

Answer (score 8):

Be careful with lock and release lock functions implemented like mentioned in one of the answers, i.e. like this:

```
int tryGetLock( char const *lockName )
{
    mode_t m = umask( 0 );
    int fd = open( lockName, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666 );
    umask( m );
    if( fd >= 0 && flock( fd, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB ) < 0 )
    {
        close( fd );
        fd = -1;
    }
    return fd;
}
```

and:

```
void releaseLock( int fd, char const *lockName )
{
    if( fd < 0 )
        return;
    remove( lockName );
    close( fd );
}
```

The problem is that releaseLock's remove call introduces a race situation bug. Let's consider there are three processes all trying to acquire the exclusive flock with nasty timing:

- Process #1 has opened the lock file, acquired the flock, and is about to call the unlock function but not yet done that.
- Process #2 has called open to open the file pointed be lockName, and has got a file descriptor of it, but not yet called flock. That is, the file pointed by lockName is opened two times now.
- Process #3 is not yet started.

With nasty timing, it is possible that process #1 calls first remove() and close() (the order doesn't matter), and then process #2 calls the flock using the file descriptor already opened, but which is not anymore the file named lockName but a file descriptor that is not linked to any directory entry.

Now, if the process #3 is started, the open() call of it creates the lockName file, and acquires the lock on it as that file is not locked. As an outcome, processes #2 and #3 both think they both own the lock on fileName -> a bug.

The issue in the implementation is that remove() (or more unlink()) only unlinks the name from the directory entry - the file descriptor referring to that file is still usable. One can create then another file having the same name, but still the already opened fd is referring to a different place.

This can be demonstrated adding delay to the lock function:

```
int tryGetLock( char const *lockName)
{
    mode_t m = umask( 0 );
    int fd = open( lockName, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666 );
    umask( m );
    printf("Opened the file. Press enter to continue...");
    fgetc(stdin);
    printf("Continuing by acquiring the lock.\n");
    if( fd >= 0 && flock( fd, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB ) < 0 )
    {
        close( fd );
        fd = -1;
    }
    return fd;
}

static const char *lockfile = "/tmp/mylock.lock";

int main(int argc, char *argv[0])
{
    int lock = tryGetLock(lockfile);
    if (lock == -1) {
        printf("Getting lock failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Acquired the lock. Press enter to release the lock...");
    fgetc(stdin);

    printf("Releasing...");
    releaseLock(lock, lockfile);
    printf("Done!\n");
    return 0;
```

}

1. Try starting process #1, and hit enter once to acquire the lock.
2. Then start process #2 on another terminal,
3. Press another enter on the terminal where process #1 is running to release the lock. 4. Continue with process #2 by pressing enter once so that it acquires the lock.
4. Then open another terminal where to run process #3. In there, press enter once to acquire the lock.

The "impossible" happens: processes #2 and #3 think they both have the exclusive lock.

This might be rare to happen in practice at least with usual applications, but nevertheless the implementation is not correct.

Also, creating a file with mode 0666 might be a security risk.

I don't have "reputation to comment", and this is also quite old question, but people are still referring to this and doing something similar, so that's why to add this note as an answer.

Comment: The purpose is to protect against other process to acquire the lock. As you correctly point out, the code is not thread safe. For thread safe code, use mutex so avoid the race condition.

Comment: You can basically leave out unlinking the lockfile entirely, since that does introduce a potential race (and in many cases /tmp, /var/run etc. are likely cleaned up automatically.)

Comment: I'll add that Named semaphores (as by `sem_open`) are probably easier to handle but aren't lockfiles (They also can't be used over NFS.). They also won't automatically release if the process dies. Another alternative is using process-shared robust mutexes over shared memory (as these indicate abandonment when the owner terminates without unlocking)

Comment: @chmike: the implementation is exactly not correct with multiple processes either.

Comment: To fix, as pointer by others, one could just leave the unlinking out. Or then one could perhaps do something similar than what is done in FreeBSD's libutils flopen() implementation: after flocking(), fstat() the fd returned by open and then stat() the lockfile (using the file name of course) and check that both answers point to the same inode.

Comment: The effect of umask is to create the file with permission 0. I should have written  `open( lockName, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0 )` to make it clear. Another process is then unable to open the file because of the permission. Only root and the owner may remove the file. The file locking is performed with the `open()`. The `flock()` is to prevent that the same process locks the file more than once.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Hasturhun's answer.  Instead of using the presence or absence of the lock file as an indicator, you need to both create the lock file if it dosen't exists and then get an exclusive lock on the file.

The advantages of this approach is that unlike many other methods of syncing programs, the OS should tidy up for you if your program exits without unlocking.

So the program structure would be something like:

```
1: open the lock file creating it if it doesn't exist
2: ask for an exclusive lock an agreed byte range in the lock file
3: when the lock is granted then
    4: <do my processing here>
    5: release my lock
    6: close the lock file
end
```

At step: you can either block waiting for the lock to be granted or return immediately.
The bytes you lock don't actually have to exist in the file.  If you can get hold of a copy of *Advanced Unix Programming* by Marc J. Rochkind, he develops a complete C library that uses this method to provide a way of syncing programs that gets tidied up by the OS, however the programs exit.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the code posted by chmike, and noticed one small imperfection. I had a problem with the race during the opening lock file. Sometimes, several threads open the lock file simultaneously.

Therefore, I removed the "remove( lockName );" line from "releaseLock()" function. I do not understand why, but somehow this action helped the situation.

I have been using the following code to test the lock files. By its output one can see when several threads start using one lock simultaneously.

```
void testlock(void) {
  # pragma omp parallel num_threads(160)
  {    
    int fd = -1; char ln[] = "testlock.lock";
    while (fd == -1) fd = tryGetLock(ln);

    cout << omp_get_thread_num() << ": got the lock!";
    cout << omp_get_thread_num() << ": removing the lock";

    releaseLock(fd,ln);
  }
}
```

Comment: The code I gave is not thread safe. It protects different process to acquire the lock. Add mutex in the functions to make it thread safe.