# Exclusive file lock (PID file implementation)

Tags: linux, posix, file-locking

I'm trying to implement a file-based exclusive lock for a daemon, which applies on a per-file basis (no inter-thread or intra-process locking). I know it's a common problem, and has some conventions established, but I am having trouble getting it right, or understanding the problem completely.

I've looked at other answers, and currently I'm using something very close to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643134, ie. using `flock` to create an advisory lock on program start. However, this doesn't do what I want; the call to `flock` always succeeds.

I'm not sure if [my code](http://ideone.com/K00Suw) is incorrect, or if I've misunderstood, and `flock` isn't meant to work across separate processes (?).

This is C++ (11) code, tested on Linux 2.6.32 (CentOS VM) and 3.12.9 (Arch), both ext4 filesystems.

Comment: It's possible that some file systems don't support advisory locking and thus always return success.

Comment: I added the FS and kernel.

Comment: It seems like ext4 should not be unreliable in that regard, though, due its wide use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was closing the file descriptor at the end of the `acquire` routine. Whoops.